# bash script that find the specific folders in sub directory and create directory in all directories recursively

Tags: shell, ubuntu, ftp

I'm new to bash script, I need to create sub folders under each directory containing specific name in ftp server.
eg:

```
A1/B1/Name1
|
|_C1
|_C2
A1/B1/Name2
|
|_C1
|_C2
A1/B1/Name3
|
|_C4
|_C5
A1/B1/Name4
|
|_C1
|_C2
```

My main directory is A1/B1 where I have Name1,2,3,4 subdirectories that has sub folders C1,C2.
I need to find which directory has C1 and C2 subfolder and create CX subfolder in all directories that has c1 and c2 recursively

Comment: For clarification: the `CX` you want to create is a completely new subfolder name; it is not that you want to create `C4` and `C5` in those folders that contain `C1` and `C2`?

Comment: yes exactly,i need to create CX sub folder in all directories that contain only C1 and C2 .Thank you for responding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#! /bin/sh -
cd A1/B1 || exit
ret=0
for dir in */; do
  if [ -d "${dir}C1" ] && [ -d "${dir}C2" ]; then
    mkdir -p -- "${dir}CX" || ret=$?
  fi
done
exit "$ret"
```

Comment: In this case name can be anything like different names(abc,bca,ghs,khdt) .I'M sorry for unclear explanation. Instead of Name* what should I replace with? Thank you so much for your response

Comment: @Nesicha, see edit.

Comment: Thank you very much , that answers my question but I get an error from this script Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "do")

Comment: I'm sorry i forgot to check the permission for execution, it works perfectly. Thank you very much